# Change ListView height to match EditText content

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-edittext

## The Issue

I have a `ListView` whose rows contain `EditText`'s of `textMultiLine`. Currently, the `ListView`'s height is `wrap_content`.

When I enter text into the rows `EditText` and it exceeds the normal height of the row, the height of the row clearly increases but the height of the `ListView` stays the same, making the `ListView` scrollable. I do not want to have to scroll to view all of its contents, I want the listview to dynamically change it's height to match its contents.

---

## The Code

I have been using this code to change the height of the `ListView` but for some reason it does not measure the contents inside of the `EditText`. It views each section as it's empty. So no matter how much text I have inside a view, it reads 325 px.

```
public static boolean setListViewHeightBasedOnItems(ListView listView) {

    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter != null) {

        int numberOfItems = listAdapter.getCount();

        // Get total height of all mItems.
        int totalItemsHeight = 0;
        for (int itemPos = 0; itemPos < numberOfItems; itemPos++) {

            View item = listAdapter.getView(itemPos, null, listView);
            item.measure(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            Log.d("ListView","" + itemPos + " Height: " + item.getMeasuredHeight());
            totalItemsHeight += item.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        // Get total height of all item dividers.
        int totalDividersHeight = listView.getDividerHeight() *
                (numberOfItems - 1);

        // Set list height.
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalItemsHeight + totalDividersHeight;
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();

        return true;

    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

---

## Visual Example

Here is an example of what I mean. Notice how in the second image, you cannot see item #2. You must scroll down within the `ListView` to see it. I am trying to make it so the height of the `ListView` changes to the exact size of the its contents.
[image]
[image]

Comment: can you please explain clearly what exactly you try to ask?

Comment: Thanks for replying @Arbaz.in. I updated `The Issue` portion with a clearer explanation. I can be terrible with explanations so if I need to make it clearer, please tell me.